# Is iPhone activation locked if Find My iPhone is disabled?

Tags: iphone, activation-lock

I have an iPhone 5c and before I hard resetted it I turned off Find My iPhone.

I'm at the setup screen I don't have a SIM card for it yet. The phone asks me for my language, country, WiFi, then tells me to insert a SIM. Is it going to tell me I need the previous AppleID and password after I get the SIM card and insert it?

Comment: You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately.

Answer (score 2):

If you disabled "Find my iPhone" you don't need an Apple ID to reactivate the phone. You will be asked for an Apple ID to log into iCloud etc. but this step can be skipped.

Since you are still stuck at the SIM prompt, it's too early to know if the device is activation locked yet. Pass that step and then you'll know.

Answer (score 0):

If the device ask you for user & pass from previous user - then it's Activation locked and you need to ask the previous user for the details.

Answer (score 0):

If https://www.icloud.com/activationlock/ tells you your device has no activation lock, you won't be asked for the previous AppleID and password.